# right float div goes behind left div with no float when window width is less than normal

Tags: html, css, css-float, scrollbar

I have two divs in a fixed header like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="commit-header_panel">
   <div id="commit-header_panel_right" style="float:right;backg..."></div>
   <div id="commit-header_panel_left"></div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#commit-header_panel
{
    background-color: #c5e8fc;
    height:74px;
}
#commit-header_panel_left
{
    height:74px;
    min-width: 630px;
}

#commit-header_panel_right
{
    min-width: 573px;
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 573? "573px": "auto" );
    height:74px;
}
```

Problem is that a right div intersects the left one when I resize a window to a less width.

I want a second one (right float) not to go behind a left one. A right div should stop going to left and let user use browser window horizontal scrollbar to look at right part if needed.

**Problem**
[image]

Comment: Use mediaqueries and define your css rules depending on the browser width (and avoid using css expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media queries to define your CSS:

- [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

For example:

```
@media all and (max-width: <SET WIDTH HERE>) and (min-width: <SET WIDTH HERE>) {
    //Define CSS here for screen size 
}
```

Or you can change the way in which you define the `width` on your `<div>` to use percentages.

Like This:

```
#commit-header_panel_left
{
    height:74px;
    min-width: 30%; //replace with required value
}

#commit-header_panel_right
{
    min-width: 30%; //replace with required value
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 573? "573px": "auto" );
    height:74px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want horizontal scrollbar then set a min-width for your header

```
#commit-header_panel
{
    min-width: 1203px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix the `width` of your `commit-header_panel` div.

Comment: This would stop the header from expanding on larger screens

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to find at what width your panels begin to overlap, and then set a min-width: Xpx; to the parent container. This allows the panels to respond dynamically to the window resize, but creates a stopping point at which the panels will no longer move.

You may also want to set your panels width to width: auto; or width: X%; as some browsers may simply snap to the min-width and not respond to the changing window size.

```
#commit-header_panel {
background-color: #c5e8fc;
height:74px;
width: 100%;
min-width: 900px;
}
```

Then be sure to clear the float with:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```